Canonical divisor of Kummer Surface
I want to prove that a Kummer surface is  K3 so, first of all, I want to focus on the canonical divisor $K_X$. Just to fix some notations: $A$ is a complex torus of the form $\mathbb{C}^2/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a lattice of rank four. $\epsilon:\tilde{A}\rightarrow A$ is the blow up of $A$ in the 16 points fixed by the involution $\tau: x \mapsto -x$. $E_i:=\epsilon^{-1}(P_i)$ is the exeptional divisor corresponding to the torsion point $P_i$. $\iota: \tilde{A} \rightarrow \tilde{A}$ is the lift of $\tau$ and $f:\tilde{A} \rightarrow \tilde{A}/\iota=:X$ is the quotient map to the Kummer surface $X$.
Now I'm going to follow the argument in Huybrechts "Lectures on K3 Surfaces" (p.3), that uses some results concerning the calculation of canonical bundle for branched coverings (they can be found in Barth, Hulek, Peters, Van de Ven "Compact Complex Surfaces", section I.16).
The formulas for the blow up $\epsilon: \tilde{A}\rightarrow A$ and for the branched covering $f: \tilde{A} \rightarrow X$ give
$$K_{\tilde{A}}=\mathcal{O}(\sum E_i),\,\,\,\,\,\, K_{\tilde{A}}=f^* K_X \otimes \mathcal{O}(\sum E_i);$$
so $$f^*K_X=\mathcal{O}_\tilde{A}.$$ Calling $\overline{E_i} \subset X$ the image of the exeptional divisor $E_i$ via $f$, we have the relation
$$f^*\mathcal{O}(\overline{E_i})=\mathcal{O}(2E_i),$$
and we also know that
$$f_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{A}}=\mathcal{O}_X\oplus L^*,$$
where $L$ is the square root of $\mathcal{O}(\sum \overline{E_i}).$
How can I conclude now?

This is not a self-contained answer. But I hope this helps.
We have by projection formula $$f_*f^* K_{X}=K_{X}\otimes f_* \mathcal O_{\tilde A}=K_X \otimes \left (\mathcal O_X\oplus L^\vee  \right )$$But since we know $f^*K_X= \mathcal O_{\tilde A}$ and $f_{*}\mathcal O_{\tilde A}=\mathcal  O_X\oplus L^\vee$, we end up with $$\mathcal O_X\oplus L^\vee \cong K_X \otimes (\mathcal O_X\oplus L^\vee)=K_X\oplus \left (K_X\otimes L^\vee\right )$$
From here, we would like to say that $K_X$ is trivial.
Taking determinants, we get $K_X^2$ is trivial which is not quite what we want.
Instead, I refer to the Krull-Schmidt theorem for coherent sheaves (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull–Schmidt_category or Krull-Schmidt-Remak for vector bundles)
This gives me either $K_X\cong \mathcal O_X$ or $K_X\cong L^\vee$. In the second case $K_X^2$ is not trivial which is a contradiction.
So $K_X\cong \mathcal O_X$ which is what we wanted.
